# Can I read the voltage (MCU ADC) with an isolated power source by opamp inputs?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, plc, biasing, rtd

I made a conceptual design to read an industrial 2- or 3-wire temperature sensor with a single 3-connection terminal.

[image]

I used an opamp in differential mode to read two terminal connections which are pulled up.

I have two separate 5 and 12 volt power sources, 12 V for sensor and 5 V for the opamp.
 
[image]

The wire connection which may be absent is fed to the non-inverted input of opamp and the wire which is always present connected to the inverted input.

My questions are:

- Can I read the voltage (MCU ADC) with different isolated power sources by opamp inputs?
- How can I detect which sensor type is connected to the opamp?

Comment: No, the opamp has a common-mode input voltage range so the input voltages need to be referenced to the opamp’s gnd. Similarly, the microcontroller’s input is referenced to its gnd, so the micro, opamp and sensor all need to share a common reference.  How to detect which sensor? You probably need a configuration option in the code to select gain, scaling etc. note the picture denotes voltage, thermocouple or resistance. No mention of RTD.

Comment: Why does your schematic show two ground symbols?

Comment: The user can short the connection at the terminal block if it's a two-wire RTD. No need to detect anything.

Comment: @Kartman That's the back of a standard temperature controller, probably made in China. The diagram shows an industrial style 3-wire RTD with thermocouple and voltage options.

Comment: Why is your schematic drawn back-to-front? Why are you using a feed-through capacitor, or is that just a mistake because you didn't bother to route the wire around it?  Why do you have upside-down ground symbols?

Comment: @Andy-aka, the sensor voltage should be 12 or 24 volts and MCU is 5v, and my question is can use different power sources by an opamp